# How can I optimize slow "for loops" when comparing 2 Objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, object

I'm trying to compare 2 Objects and see if there's any same values.
My Objects are like this:

```
object_a = [
    {id: 4, score: 2},
    {id: 5, score: 0},
    {id: 2, score: 1},
    {id: 1, score: 0},
    {id: 3, score: 2},
];

object_b = [
    {
        id: 1,
        questions: [
            {
                id: 1,
                choices: [
                    {id: 2, score: ''},
                    {id: 3, score: ''},
                ],
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                choices: [
                    {id: 6, score: ''},
                    {id: 8, score: ''},
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
];
```

So for example I need to get `object_a[2]` and `object_a[4]` and save them in a state variable and I'm using `react native`...

Here is my code so far, It's working as expected but it's slow, it takes at least `1s` to run this code when my component is mounted...

```
state = {
    theScore: null,
    theDescription: '',
    checked: null,
};

async getFromStorage() {
    try {
        let jsonVal = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@answer');
        if (jsonVal !== null) {
            return JSON.parse(jsonVal);
        }
    } catch (e) {
    }
};

componentDidMount() {
    InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
        const myRoute = this.props;
        this.getFromStorage().then(((storeValue) => {
            if (storeValue !== null) {
                if (storeValue.length > 0) {
                    for (let i = 0; i < myRoute.choices.length; i++) {
                        if (storeValue.some(storage => storage.choice_id === myRoute.choices[i].id)) {
                            this.setState({checked: myRoute.choices[i].id},
                                function () {});
                            this.setState({theScore: myRoute.choices[i].score},
                                function () {});
                        }
                    }
                    for (let i = 0; i < storeValue.length; i++) {
                        if (myRoute.choices.some(choice => choice.question_id ===
                            storeValue[i].question_id) &&
                            storeValue[i].description !== '') {
                            this.setState({theDescription: storeValue[i].description},
                                function () {});
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }));
    });
}
```

So as you see I used two `for loops` because count need to be different and also I used `some()` to check if the value in `object_b` exists in `object_a` or not. I don't know if there is a better way for doing this or not. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can modify you code like the code below

```
if (storeValue !== null) {
  if (storeValue.length > 0) {
    let checked, theScore, theDescription;
    for (let i = 0; i < myRoute.choices.length; i++) {
      if (storeValue.some(storage => storage.choice_id === myRoute.choices[i].id)) {
        checked = myRoute.choices[i].id;
        theScore = myRoute.choices[i].score;
      }
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < storeValue.length; i++) {
      if (
        myRoute.choices.some(choice => choice.question_id === storeValue[i].question_id) &&
        storeValue[i].description !== ''
      ) {
        theDescription = storeValue[i].description;
      }
    }
    this.setState({ checked, theScore, theDescription });
  }
}
```

You shouldn't call `this.setState` multiple time in the same function

Try to wrap up and call `only once` at the end of the function

Comment: Thanks for your great tip. It helps a lot, but still it's slow, can I use for loops any better way? maybe some method instead of `some()`?

Comment: it still slows because of `AsyncStorage.getItem` is a async function, it need time to complete

Comment: oh I see... Thanks